# Listarray overflow

Tags: c#, csv

I have a problem reading data from a CSV file. As in the following example I try to read in the list information from two different columns. With the query "EndOfStream" or with a count variable larger than about 6000 I get the error: "The index was out of range". However, with a count variable of 4000, the code works exactly as it should. I do not understand my mistake.

```
List<string> gpsGGA = new List<string>();
List<string> gpsRMC = new List<string>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btn_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path;
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try { 
            path = file.FileName;
            StreamReader data = new StreamReader(path);
            data.ReadLine();                                        //Header verwerfen
            gpsGGA.Clear();
            gpsRMC.Clear();
            for(int i=0; i<8000; i++)//while (!data.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] substring = data.ReadLine().Split(';');
                gpsGGA.Add(substring[11]);
                gpsRMC.Add(substring[12]);
            }
            data.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are not using the loop counter as an index, I would guess that you have bad data at around line 6000 in the CSV file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your codes makes it hard to guess wheter the error is coming from reading the file or the file content itself.

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` which takes the file path and returns its lines as an array, regardless of the number of lines that you specify in the foor loop, which by the way can cause errors if the number of lines is is not equal to 8000.

```
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        gpsGGA.Clear();
        gpsRMC.Clear();
        string[] lines= File.ReadAllLines(file.FileName);
        foreach(String line in lines)
        {
           string[] substring = line.Split(';');
           gpsGGA.Add(substring[11]);
           gpsRMC.Add(substring[12]);
        }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The index was out of range is probably caused by some lines which have invalid data

For example this is line 6000 : `sdd;dfdf;dfdf;00;dfdf;555`

When you try to get element at index 11 or 12, it doesn't exist because this line has only 6 elements

Comment: yeah for sure there was bad data! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is commented out:

```
for(int i=0; i<8000; i++)//while (!data.EndOfStream)
```

The while loop that is commented out intended to only read data while exists.

I added a using statement to ensure the file gets closed.  I added an IsNullOrEmpty check in case there's a blank line at the end of the file, so you don't get an error with that.

```
using (StreamReader data = new StreamReader(path))
{

    data.ReadLine();                                        //Header verwerfen
    gpsGGA.Clear();
    gpsRMC.Clear();
    int counter = 0;
    while (!data.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = data.ReadLine();
        if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            string[] substring = line.Split(';');
            if ( substring.Length < 13 )
                 throw new ApplicationException("Malformated Data At Line " + counter.ToString());
            gpsGGA.Add(substring[11]);
            gpsRMC.Add(substring[12]);
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```